# How to insert character in firefox style editor?

Tags: css, firefox

e.g. I have such CSS code to edit on the fly:

```
nav {
    margin: 100px auto; 
    text-align: center;
}
```

It seems that the ONLY way to edit it through firefox's `inspect element` is the high light the part and overwrite it.

EVERY TIME when I try to move the cursor somewhere, delete some characters and add something new (for example, move to the position between two zeros, delete the first one and add 5 such that 100 changes to 150), it automatically brings back the characters I have just deleted. See below:

```
nav {
    margin: 1050px auto; 
    text-align: center;
}
```

The deleted zero automatically goes back. It turns out to be super annoying to me but I couldn't get around this issue at all. Can anyone tell me how to edit the style just the way the same as people do in any text editor instead of it bringing back EVERYTHING I have deleted, making the edition totally messed up.

Comment: it works fine for me.  Are you opening up new pages though? If you make changes, then go to a different page or (possibly have another get http request on the same page), then the editor will reset back to normal.

Comment: No. I'm editing on the fly on the same page. I got really pissed off by this so I'm asking if there's some ways around without highlighting everything I am to edit.

Comment: And you've used firefox with no issues in the past? I know that if you hit the delete key and nothing is selected, (which can happen by accident) it can also make the browser go back a page, thus resetting all your styles.  Your issue sounds really weird, I can only recommend to try a uninstall and reinstall, or try chrome.

Comment: Obviously the browser does not bring the page back. It simply added whatever I've deleted in the style editor back in the place they were. It's my first time trying editing on the fly, and the browser seems a bit (pronounced 'lot') unfriendly.

Comment: In Firefox , i use EDITCSS simple and light. You can even open and save files.